# MS Access - How can I filter 2 fields, each with 2 different values

Tags: mysql, ms-access

MS Access - How can I filter 2 fields, each with 2 different values

```
SELECT *
where plants.name like "abc*" or "*def*" or where plants.source like "123*" or "*456*"
FROM plants;
```

Tried many ()"' but cannot get it to work

It should be simple but I just cannot get it too work, any isdeas please.

Comment: Each condition must be complete. `.. where plants.name like "abc*" or plants.name like "*def*" or plants.source like "123*" or plants.source like "*456*"`

Comment: I get an error message trying to save the query. Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your ***FROM*** clause position before ***WHERE***.

If the two double conditions must occur, use ***AND*** instead ***OR***.

Please, try this:

```
 SELECT *
     FROM plants
         where (name like "abc*" or name like "*def*") AND
         where (source like "123*" or source like "*456*");
```